# How can I accept a supertype of generic parameter on a single object?

Tags: java, generics, super

Is it possible to accept only supertypes of the generic Type of a class?

What I'm looking for is something like:

```
class <T extends Object> MyClass {

    public <TS super T> void myMethod(TS someObjectSuperToTheClass) {
         //do stuff
    }

}
```

I don't really need it anymore (and it's probably not all that useful to begin with) but I'm curious if this is at all possible and if not, why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you cannot!  Only wildcards can have a `super` bound.

Answer (score 6):

Think about what it would mean in this case.

You want to assert that `TS` is either `T`, or any of its superclasses.  But since `TS` is merely a reference, the actual `someObjectSuperToTheClass` parameter can be `TS` or a subclass.

Putting both halves together, in comes out that your code is entirely equivalent to

```
public void myMethod(Object someObjectSuperToTheClass) { //do stuff }
```

since together, you've got that `TS` can walk as high as it wants up the class hierarchy, and the parameter can walk down as far as it wants.

What was it you were *trying* to constrain the parameter to, with this syntax?

Comment: in hindsight i wanted to constrain the argument to having at least on shared interface. but thats of course always the case.
i guess i wanted TS super T 'but not Object itself' :)

Comment: and thanks for explaining why it would make no sense IF it was possible